# c++ ostream operator overloading text formatting while trying to skip over intervals

Tags: c++, formatting, operator-overloading, ostream, ranged-loops

I know how to write an overloaded `ostream<<` operator as a friend method for a class object. I know how to traverse through single and double for loops. But trying to achieve a specific `text format` is proving to be a tough challenge.

Here is what my function looks like:

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const DeckOfCards& deck  ) {
    for ( auto& c : deck.getDeck() ) {
        if ( c.get()->getValue() != "Joker" ) {
            out << c.get()->getValue() << " "
                << c.get()->getSuit() << ", ";
        } else {
            out << c.get()->getSuit() << " "
                << c.get()->getValue() << ", ";
        }
    }
    out << std::endl;

    return out;
}
```

My main is simple:

```
int main() {
    DeckOfCards deck1;
    DeckOfCards deck2( false );

    std::cout << "Standard Deck:\n" << deck1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Expanded Deck:\n" << deck2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It's output is as expected.

```
Standard Deck:
Ace Spades, 2 Spades...


Queen Diamonds, King Diamonds,

Expanded Deck:
Ace Spades, 2 Spades...

Queen Diamonds, King Diamonds, Little Joker, Big Joker,
```

And yes, there is a trailing comma at the end as I am not concerned with it. The above was only used to test to see if the construction of my class was valid.

I want to edit the above `operator<<` overload so that the printed display would look as follows:

```
Standard Deck:
Spades:   Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King
Hearts:   Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King
Clubs:    Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King
Diamonds: Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King

Expanded Deck:
Spades:   Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King
Hearts:   Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King
Clubs:    Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King
Diamonds: Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King
Little Joker, Big Joker
```

I would prefer to try and keep the loop similar to the one above simple while using the `for( auto& e : container)`:  I would also like to print the suit name once followed by all of the values once per line for each suit. If the deck is expanded the same applies except the last two cards would be on a separate last line as shown above.

I can not seem to figure out how to do the intervals while using modern c++'s

```
for ( auto& e : container ) {
   ...
}
```

type of Loops. I have tried to many different things to show here and to keep this question as short as possible any suggestions would be extremely helpful.

If you need to know more about the `class` `DeckOfCards` that is being used feel free to ask: The class is quite simple; it contains a `vector<shared_ptr<Card>>` and a single bool to represent if the deck is standard or expanded and `Card` has 2 strings.

**Edit**

I made some adjustments to my loop above based on the advise of user: `Mitchel0022` for using `% 13 == 0` as a condition with an extra variable.

The layout is extremely close as to what I want to achieve. The modified operator now looks like:

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const DeckOfCards& deck  ) {

    int cardsPrinted = 0;
    const size_t width = std::string( "Diamonds: " ).size();

    for ( auto& c : deck.getDeck()  ) {
        if ( cardsPrinted % 13 == 0 && cardsPrinted < 52 ) {
            out << "\n" << std::setw( width ) << c.get()->getSuit() << ": ";
        } else if ( cardsPrinted < 52 ) {
            out << c.get()->getValue() << " ";

        }
        cardsPrinted++;
    }   
    out << std::endl;

    if ( !deck.isStandard() ) {
        out << std::setw( width ) << deck.getDeck()[52].get()->getSuit() << " "
            << deck.getDeck()[52].get()->getValue() << ", "
            << deck.getDeck()[53].get()->getSuit() << " "
            << deck.getDeck()[53].get()->getValue() << std::endl;
    }

    return out;
}
```

However the output being very close to what I want is missing 1 element and it now looks like this:

```
Standard Deck:

    Spades: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King
    Hearts: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King
     Clubs: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King
  Diamonds: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King

Expanded Deck:

    Spades: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King
    Hearts: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King
     Clubs: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King
  Diamonds: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King
    Little Joker, Big Joker
```

The only element not printed is the Ace. It is skipping over the first value; probably has something to do with the `if statement` and the current value of the `cardsPrinted` variable.

**Final Edit**

All I had to do was add this line into the `if` statement:

```
out << c.get()->getValue() << " ";
```

after pushing the `suit` into the stream. Now I have a clean looking output display for my DeckOfCards class all thanks to user `Mitchel0022`'s advice from the comment section.

Comment: you could use the fact that the array is sorted and there are 13 cards. Something like `if cardsPrintedSoFar % 13 is 0 then print new line + suit`

Comment: @Mitchel0022 Hmm possible good tip; didn't think to use modulo operator; sometimes the simplest of things can evade you. However how would I factor in the `%13` within the `for (auto& c : deck) {...}`? Or would I have to expand it out to an actual full for loop?

Comment: You could simply use an extra variable to keep track of how many card you have gone through, alternatively you could implement a true for loop and use that index

Comment: I can but I like the `auto` loops they look much cleaner...

Comment: In that case yeah, just declare a `cardsPrintedSoFar = 0` and then do `cardsPrintedSoFar++` somewhere in the loop

Comment: Yeah; working on it...

Comment: @Francis Cugler - using "`auto` loops" (by which you seem to mean a range-based loop) because they "look much cleaner" is counter-productive.  Roughly speaking, if you ever need to check the number of loop iterations within the loop body, a range-based loop is a poor choice compared with an index based loop.   You're just making the outer loop construct look clean, but increasing messiness of the logic within the loop body.

Comment: @Peter true; just trying to get a feel of what it's like when using the `ranged based loops`. But I think it comes down to the context or the use of the loop on which to use. If you are iterating over every single element of a container and performing a simple operation, then the `ranged-based-loop` would be better; but if there are complex operations based on indexed values, then a normal loop would definitely be more appropriate.

Comment: @Peter Oh and I do know that they are ranged base for loops... I was just using auto within the comments.

Comment: @Mitchel0022 thank you for the advice; I now have a nice clean output display of a deck of cards; either it be a standard deck or one with jokers.